# How to wrap a long equation in Latex

Tags: formatting, equations

I have a very big equation and using split or multiline is not helping. How do i wrap it and how do i make sure thatRHS of the eqn is always on the right side of equal to ('=') even when line is changed

```
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  m_{12}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue} \})= K'* [m_{1}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue} \})*m_{2}(\{    \emph{Red},\emph{Blue} \})+m_{1}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue} \})*m_{2}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue},\emph{Green} \})+m_{2}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue} \})*m_{1}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue},\emph{Green} \})]
 \end{split}
 \end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use aligned:

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    m_{12}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue} \}) 
    = K' * \bigl[ & m_{1}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue} \})*m_{2}(\{    \emph{Red},\emph{Blue} \}) \\
     + & m_{1}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue} \})*m_{2}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue},\emph{Green} \}) \\
     + & m_{2}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue} \})*m_{1}(\{ \emph{Red},\emph{Blue},\emph{Green} \})\bigr]
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: I'd use `\mathit` rather than `\emph`

Comment: @egreg The italic font is strange anyway, I just copied from the question.

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried using the `align` environment?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  m_{12}(\{Red,Blue\})&=K'*[m_1 (\{Red,Blue\})*m_2(\{Red,Blue\})\\
                      &\qquad +m_1(\{Red,Blue\})*m_2(\{Red,Blue,Green\})\\
                      &\qquad +m_2(\{Red,Blue\})*m_1(\{Red,Blue,Green\})]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: using `\mathit{Red,Blue}` instead of just the words would result in a nicer appearance with respect to intra-word kerning.  (the alignment is very nice, however.)

Comment: Any easy way to line up the `m_1` on the first two lines?

Comment: @Eric Old question, but `&` is used for alignment, so just put them in front of the `m_1`s (replacing the other ones).